# how to prevent bootstrap dropdowns from toggling back if it has form elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

http://plnkr.co/edit/rO1cev9Pw7TNbeGLioVk?p=preview

How should I prevent the dropdown from closing If I want to have multiple checkboxes and check or uncheck more than one at a time?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863821/bootstrap-dropdown-closing-when-clicked

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since the `dropdownToggle` observes click events to close the dropdown menu, you will need to stop propagation of click events on checkbox elements. This can be easily done like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
```

And the working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/AcbhOkKr2rGrPeoge26H?p=preview

Comment: It would be cool if angular-ui bootstrap had multiselect dropdown menus

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue with bootstraps `dropdown` and I wanted a native ( angular only ) implementation of a multi- dropdown select ( Basically I wanted to replace chosen since it depends on jquery ) . So I wrote one myself .

Here is the plunker demonstrating the dropdown :

http://plnkr.co/edit/lxewJUN8li9YQj9h1cIz?p=preview

It has support for `Select All` as well if you are in need of something like that.

Hope this helps.

**NOTE :** For some reason it only works with the unstable branch.

Comment: cool! why is there a scrollbar in the dropdown list, can we remove it?

Comment: Thats just a css change. I have removed it now.