# How to close bootstrap 3 dropdown when we click outside on a tablet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am doing this and it works fine on the desk:

```
$(document).on("click", function(){
  $(".dropdown-toggle").removeClass("open");
});
```

But on the iPad that it isn't working and my dropdown remains open

Comment: Mobile Safari doesn't fire click events unless it deems the element to be clickable; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click#Safari_Mobile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `touchstart` and  `touchend` events with touch devices:

```
$(document).on("click touchend", function(){
    $(".dropdown-toggle").removeClass("open");
});
```

Comment: ok yes it worked. however you do need also to include click as it is required for both i guess,  so "click touchend" but yes, i will accept. thanks

Comment: so touchend is when the user finished to click and touchstart when it starts? or what is the difference in plain words? Thanks

Comment: It is exactly as you have said, it is usally preferable to do something when the touch ends, I myself also find it better from an UX standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

This answer relates to *navbar* menus, rather than general *dropdowns*, but I came across this while looking for the answer to my own similar question (close hamburger menus when tapping outside), so thought I'd post an alternative solution for anyone else, as the accepted answer does not work with *hamburger submenus* (tapping to open a *submenu* would close the *hamburger* menu).

This answer was based on the accepted answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23770501/3105807) answer, as well as NickGreen's comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2868645/3105807) answer.

```
$('html').on('click, touchend', function (e) {
    // Close hamburger menu when tapping outside
    if ($(e.target).closest('.navbar').length == 0) {
        var opened = $('.navbar-collapse').hasClass('collapse in');
        if (opened === true) {
            $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this snippet if I don't want to close any dropdown on the page when the user clicks inside it.

```
$(document).on('click touchend', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('.open').length === 0) {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').parent().removeClass('open');
  }
});
```