# Dropdown menu with input inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to create a dropdown menu combine input inside as my image ,i use bootstrap

```
<i>
 <div class="btn-group dropdown" dropdown >
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" dropdown-toggle>
            Dropdown
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="buttonuser"  role="menu">
            <li>
                <p>Add to</p>
                <input type="text" id="findUser" class="form-control">
            </li>
            <li><a href>Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href>Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href>Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li>Remove</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
</i>
```

but when i click on input , menu dropdown hide all , i dont want this , please tell me how i do

Comment: You need to provide your CSS and any JS you may be using as well...

Comment: Try this idea to stopPropagation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863821/bootstrap-dropdown-closing-when-clicked

Comment: This has been fixed in upcoming Bootstrap v3.3.5: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16072

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this script before the end of body or where you have your JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.dropdown-menu input, .dropdown-menu label').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#findUser').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) should help you

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap 3.3.5 this works by default.