# HTML align dropdown elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to insert custom element(not a simple link ) to drop down.
Here is my code:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
        <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
            Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li role="menuitem">
                <div style="display:block">
                    <span>Action</span>
                    <button type="submit" class="invisible-input pull-right"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-lg"></i></button>
                    <button type="submit" class="invisible-input pull-right"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-lg"></i></button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I faced problem, that I cannot align label of Item like another ones.
Maybe someone can give me a helping hand to make strings in drop down aligned.

Here is a picture what I get:
[image]

I use angular, bootstrap and bootstrap-UI.

**Fiddle link:**  http://jsfiddle.net/dJDHd/1165/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be a simple addition to your custom CSS file:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > div {
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/k6exqq8d/)**

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/dJDHd/1166/)** (Fork of OP's code - thanks [Manoj Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4813913/manoj-kumar))

Comment: can you answer one additional question, maybe you know easy way to not close dropdown when I click one of these "custom buttons"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863821/bootstrap-dropdown-closing-when-clicked